# Redirection with vue-router in navigation guards

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using `vue.js` and I would like to be able to redirect a user to another URL within the navigation guard `beforeRouteEnter`

The idea is to get the current city of the user if it is not already in the url and redirect it.

For instance if you type `london.example.com` you're fine.
If you type `example.com` I want the user to be redirected to `london.example.com`

#### Problem

`window.location.replace` seems to have no effect

`next()` append the response in the URL instead of prepending it.

#### Code

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
const subdomain = window.location.hostname.split('.')[0]
if (!subdomain) {
  axios.get('/api/getCity').then((response) => {
    if (response.data) {
      window.location.replace(response.data + '.localhost:8080')
      next({ path: 'http://' + response.data + '.localhost:8080' })
    }
  })
}
```

},

Comment: What about `window.location.href = response.data + '.localhost:8080'`?

Comment: Already tried that, same result. Notice : the programme do go into the `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location.href = 'http://' + response.data + '.localhost:8080'
```